# ML model prediction for fluctuating data

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, xgboost

I have a dataset containing 6 inputs and 1 output (Note: it is not time-series dataset). ML model developed for prediction output in python. I have tried different ML algorithms for training the model such as linear regression, random forest, XGB and Decision Tree Regressor. With all these models, training prediction seems good but testing prediction is very poor (clearly training model is overfitted).
I would like to solve two issues, 1. Overfitting of training model and 2. Prediction in fluctuations of output.
Attaching the dataset, code in python and outputs of model for reference.
Appreciate if anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong or which ML algorithm can be helpful to predict such fluctuations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xgboost as xgb

data = pd.read_excel('Dataset.xlsx')

X1 = data.iloc[:,0:6]
X = X1.values

y1 = data.iloc[:,6:]
y2 = y1.values
y = y2.ravel()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model =xgb.XGBRegressor()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

#Train prediction
ytp= model.predict(x_train)    
R2_training = r2_score(y_train, ytp)
mape_training = np.mean(np.abs((y_train-ytp)/y_train)) * 100
mae_training = mean_absolute_error(y_train, ytp)

#Test prediction
y_pred= model.predict(x_test)    
R2_testing = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
mape_testing = np.mean(np.abs((y_test-y_pred)/y_test)) * 100
mae_testing = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

print('Training R2', round(R2_training,2))
print('Testing R2', round(R2_testing,2))
print('Training MAPE', round(mape_training,2))
print('Testing MAPE', round(mape_testing,2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Y_max = y_test.max()
Y_min = y_test.min() 
X_ref = Y_ref = np.linspace(Y_min, Y_max, 100)
ax.plot(X_ref, Y_ref, color='k')   
ax.plot(y_train, ytp, 'o', color='blue', label = 'Train')
ax.plot(y_test, y_pred, 'o', color='red', label = 'Test')
ax.set_xlabel('Actual')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=True)
ax.grid()
fig.tight_layout()  

bb=\[x for x in range(len(y_test))\]
plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
plt.plot(bb, y_test, marker='.', label="Testing data")
plt.plot(bb, y_pred, 'r', label="testing prediction")
plt.tight_layout()
sns.despine(top=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07)
plt.ylabel('Gamma', size=15)
plt.xlabel('samples', size=15)
plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.show();
```

[Actual_vs_predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j05J8.png)
[Testing prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GSUq.png)

Answer (score -1):

**model overfitting**

There are a few techniques you can implement to reduce model overfitting:

- Collect more data if possible
- Use early stopping
- Tune parameters in models (can use grid search or random search to tune params.  In xgboost tune max_depth, min_child_weight, gamma )
- Increase test size sample (maybe try 0.3 instead of 0.2)
- Try k fold cross-validation instead of a hold-out test set (k fold uses subsets of data)
- add noise to dataset (this works as a regularization effect however, be  careful as can be a double-edged sword)

implement early stopping- https://machinelearningmastery.com/avoid-overfitting-by-early-stopping-with-xgboost-in-python/

parameter tuning- https://machinelearningmastery.com/hyperparameter-optimization-with-random-search-and-grid-search/

implement k fold cross validation- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

**fluctuations of output**

From the code above it looks like you're not normalizing your data before model training. Data normalization transforms your features to be on a similar scale
and can often improve training and stability of a model. this could possibly iron out your issue of fluctuations in your outputs.

more info about normalization-[https://deepchecks.com/glossary/normalization-in-machine-learning/#:~:text=Normalization%20is%20a%20data%20preparation,be%20normalized%20for%20machine%20learning.](https://deepchecks.com/glossary/normalization-in-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=Normalization%20is%20a%20data%20preparation,be%20normalized%20for%20machine%20learning.)

normalizing data using sklearn- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html